# I only want to sign in to Office Outlook, not the rest of the apps

Tags: microsoft-office

when i enter my company email into my outlook, it signs me in everywhere, even though i select "Sign into this app only" it still signs me into all office apps like word, excel etc.

is there any fix for this issue?

Comment: I believe that is normal behavior and cannot be changed. Certainly Office 365 signs you into all its apps. Is that the version of Office you are using?

Comment: Microsoft went to SSO [Single Sign On] logins ~2015ish, so this is normal behavior if you're using Outlook Web Access [OWA], and not the Outlook desktop program. OWA is apart of the Office online suite, so signing in to any online Office application will sign into the online Office suite as they're one and the same AFAIK. A workaround for this would be using a separate browser, or an InPrivate session, for OWA.

Comment: Yes, I agree that it's a normal behavior since Office 2013.

Comment: Im using Microsoft office 2019, downloaded verision not the web version. i want to log in with my work email in outlook Only. but it signs me into every other app as well, even though there is a checkbox during login in outlook that says "sign into this app alone"